# Implementing user links powered by REST JSON API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

My web app has a simple UI powered by React.  It's a single page only, no routing.  All interaction with the server is via a REST API: POST to the API to take actions, GET JSON from the API to update the UI (which React does).  There is no server side templating whatsoever.

What is the recommended method to implement user actions via buttons and hyperlinks? I'd like e.g. clicking on a `<a>` hyperlink to perform a POST, and then GET new JSON which will cause React to rerender with new `props`.  I can hardcode in Javascript to do this, of course.  However, I'm looking for recommended ways to do this using React.  Idioms, components, best practices, or just the common way to do this.

Comment: did my answer help you SRobertJames? or do you need some more help? thanks

Comment: @RedBaron Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this would be done by clicking on the button, making the request and then setting the state of your component with what you get back in the response. React will then re-render like you say with the different updated state values.

You can also then pass this updated state down to child components in "props".

A good pattern for UX is to have some loading state and toggle that to true once you start making the request and toggle it to false after you have the data to display on your page.

The most common react fetching pattern is in `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` but your use case is for button clicks so they won't apply here

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact complexity of your components and relation between them it's hard to recommend the way it is different in every situation.

If the user action and UI which need to update is in the same component you can use the state to re-render the component.

However, if the user action and UI which need to update are part of different component then need to update the component using props. Where you will need to know the concept of lifting state up.

But it will also decision-making concert where the lifted state lives in the hierarchy of parent and their child’s, and how far the date needs to travel in the hierarchy you may need to use context in such cases.